Switch from GUI to terminal only
Note: excuse me if my question is not well described. I have revised it many times.
I have a Lubuntu 1.4.0 machine. I wish to use only the terminal, and Firefox browser, and remove all other GUI packages except what the browser needs to run.
I want to do this because

Moy computer is very, very old and is tired.
I want to educate myself more on Linux and get used to such an environment, as I will become a security engineer in the future.

Is there an alternative way, maybe disable certain graphics components without uninstalling them? If not, how do I remove all graphics components except the browser's graphic dependencies? And finally, is it advisable to do it? If not, can you tell me why?

You can't go "terminal only" if you want a GUI web browser - probably the closest you'll get is to have Firefox + a lightweight terminal emulator on top of a simple window manager like openbox - or go full kiosk mode for the browser and switch to a virtual terminal for CLI. This older answer A kiosk solution with Ubuntu+Firefox might be a good starting point.

What are your system specificiations? Switch to Raspberry Pi OS for desktop. It is lighter than Lubuntu https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/raspberry-pi-desktop/

What is a Lubuntu 1.4.0 machine?  Lubuntu releases are year.month as they're standard Ubuntu products managed by community team members. Is the 1.4.0 a LXQt version or something else? The command lsb_release -a will show your release details, or just use neofetch Lubuntu include but what is the 1.4.0 version?  (there are many packages of that version in rather different releases so it may not be LXQt).  Lubuntu provides an openbox session on most releases; this is a desktop-free system (ie. using openbox as WM only!), thus no panel, only the rather limiter obmenu.

Do note, that the very simple openbox interface provided by Lubuntu (by default) varies on version, and for some releases that means you just get a black screen with mouse-pointer alone (ie. not even wallpaper!)... but you've not said what Lubuntu release you're using.. Openbox is bare and basic, though you can configure it to do more, but that's on you. (basic) mention is made in Lubuntu manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/A/tips_and_tricks.html?highlight=openbox being the 24.04 manual; adjust URL if you're using another release as you haven't said)

@steeldriver understood. I thought there may be a way to -say- use terminal only, and open the browser only when needed.
What you said about Firefox, plus a lightweight window manager seems ideal. Thank you.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Understood. Is it stable and secure?

@guiverc Correct. 1.4.0 is the LXQT version. I have Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
So, if I am correct, you're suggesting that I use openbex as a window manager, without the desktop, and run Firefox on top of it? Are there any system configurations I need to make before removing the desktop or before running Firefox on top of Openbox without a desktop?

@GuteShel Yes it is stable and secure. It is based on Debian 11

@ArchismanPanigrahi That cheered me up. Thank you, mr Archisman.

It's up to you what you use, you can even run a web browser without WM and just on Xorg if you wish, but without WM you won't have window borders, close buttons, window control via mouse etc as those come from the WM (but you can still control much via terminal), however a WM alone is without any desktop and thus still light. Lubuntu is pre-configured to work without LXQt, but openbox config is rather frugal. Just select openbox session when you login & explore.

@guiverc Understood! Thank you very much, mr guiverc.

Be aware of what you'll be using, when you login with a WM, there is no menu, no panel, no wallpaper... just a black screen is expected (ie. no desktop is running, so none of those features; with LXQt the background is drawn by pcmanfm-qt). You can right-click the black-background to get the OBMENU (openbox menu) though...  Of course you may want to still tailor the system configs to provide more, or even less... You could also use a different WM if its more to your needs/tastes.

@guiverc Understood. I may try it out on a VM, get used to it, then use it on my real machine. Again, thank you very much, mr guiverc.
